# Pre and post intervention (same subjects) with different outcome (successful and unsuccesful) as a result of the treatment

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, paired-data, ancova

i have pre and post measurements of biodata (20 clinical measurements) taken before and after the treatment from a group of 30 people, out of which I have 20 successful and 10 unsuccessful subjects. I want to analyse the differences in these clinical measurements with regards to their (pre/post) measurement and the group differences (successful vs unsuccessful). which method is most appropriate? I also have to correct for their age and BMI.

Comment: Are you using a clinical rating scale to define "successful"? If so, you would be better off using the raw clinical rating scale scores than using "success" because you lose information when turning a continuous variable into a dichotomous one

Comment: It is a binary outcome, as a result of treatment. Measured by yes for successful or no for unsuccessful.